# Where are these Node generated CronJobs stored?

Tags: node.js, cron

I have created CronJobs using the following code using [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron), however I can't find them to destroy them.  On Debian BullsEye, I have checked /etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly, /etc/cron.monthly and there isn't anything there.

This processes is run under www-data

```
        new cronjob('* ' + sMarr[i] + ' ' + sHarr[i] + ' * * *', function(x) {
      
          shell.exec('ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -i '+iUarr[x]+' -c:a aac -t 00:'+dMarr[x]+':'+dSarr[x]+' -f hls /mnt/streamlinks/'+outputName+'.m3u8&', {async:true});
        }.bind(null, i), null,  true, 'Europe/London').start();
        console.log("made cron job");
      }catch{
        console.log("Error creating cronjob");  
      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These cron jobs are created in memory, they are not created at the system level. This allows the module to work on different OSes (e.g. Windows).

When you create a job you can hold a reference to it and then stop it any time using job.stop().

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('Sample cron job...');
}, null, false);

// Start the cron job...
job.start();

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Stopping cron job..");
    // Kill the cron job
    job.stop();
}, 10000)
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains a lot.  I am using anonymous instantiation, and not stopping the job, as I thought it was system level.  What is the most efficient manner for destroying previously generated CronJobs on a live system?

Comment: Hmmm, if you don't have a reference to a cron job I don't know how you would stop it. You may be able to enumerate the active jobs, but I don't know of an api function to do this. If you wish to stop running cron jobs, you'll probably need to find the running node script and stop it.